How do we enforce the domain entity valdiation which are part of domain service
I have a usecase where lets say we need to create an entity but business logic demands few checks from the db or other entity,service
Is it good to pass the domain service in the entity creation as parameter so that we can enforce the validation every time its created
In the following example, the creation of the ProductEntity is separated from the domain service logic. This raises a concern: Can we still create a product without validating it through the domain service in persistence? Is this a common case, and should we ensure this validation every time during a code review, or enforce it in some way?
Example 1:
class ProductService {
  constructor(productDomainService, productFactory, productRepository) {
    this.productDomainService = productDomainService;
    this.productFactory = productFactory;
    this.productRepository = productRepository;
  }

  async registerProduct(productName, price) {
    // Check if a product with the same name already exists
    const exists = await this.productDomainService.isExistSameProductName(productName);
    if (exists) {
      throw new Error("A product with the same name already exists.");
    }

    // Create a new product instance
    const product = this.productFactory.create(productName, price);

    // Save the product
    await this.productRepository.save(product);
  }
}


Ref: Introduction to Domain Services in DDD

In this example, the product entity creation is separate from the domain service logic. We can potentially create a product without validating it through the domain service and directly save it. Is this a general practice, and should this be enforced or cross-checked in code reviews to ensure that validation isn't skipped?
Example 2:

// domain/entities/templateEntity.ts
export interface ITemplateProps extends IEntityProps {
  name: string;
  handlerId: string;
  isPublished: boolean;
  organizationId: string;
  createdById: string;
  modifiedById: string;
}

export class TemplateEntity extends Entity<ITemplateProps> {
  private constructor(props: ITemplateProps, id?: string) {
    super(props, id);
  }

  // getters

  public static create(
    props: ITemplateProps,
    guid?: string
  ): Result<TemplateEntity, AppError> {
    const handlerTemplates = new TemplateEntity(props, guid);
    return Result.ok<TemplateEntity>(handlerTemplates);
  }
}

Business Rule:

The default value for isPublished is false.
To set isPublished to true, it must pass a validation that depends on another entity (IAnotherEntity[]), which is not directly part of this entity and might need to be fetched separately from persistence.

Options for changing isPublished:

// Application/someService.ts

templateEntity = await this.repository.getTemplateEntityById(id);
anotherEntityArray = await this.repository.getAnotherEntityArray();

// Option 1: Using domain method
# templateEntity.setIsPublished(anotherEntityArray);

// Option 2: Using Domain Service
# DomainService.setIsPublished(anotherEntityArray, templateEntity);

// Option 3: Directly
 TemplateEntity.create({
  ...templateEntity.props,
  isPublished: true
});

await this.repository.save(result);

In this example, we can bypass the validation when setting isPublished, as it's not enforced during entity creation.
So, should we pass the domain service into the entity's factory method to ensure validation, even if it makes the method impure ?
TemplateEntity.create({
  ...templateEntity.props,
  isPublished: true
}, this.domainService);

Or is there a better way to handle this situation?



Your first approach is objectively better because its very easy to read the code and understand what's going on - my eyes glaze over when I try to understand the second.
In the first approach, it would be better to pass in interfaces / abstractions rather than reference a concrete implementations, but I would only do that if you know you're going to have different implementations of the domain services (etc) that you want to pass in.
You can create a mechanism to load/return service implementations so that you don't need to pass them in - e.g. you can specify them using static config-keys, or even dynamically pass them in:
// The purpose of this code is only to demonstrate an alternative way
// to reference a domain service without passing it in.
public class SomeApplicationService
{
  // The AmazingAbstractionService.GetServiceReference() can work
  // anyway you want it to, e.g. load a service implementation based
  // on the value of a config setting, so here all you need to do 
  // is pass in the appropriate config key.  Here we use a static value.
  private IProductDomainService iProductDomainService = AmazingAbstractionService.GetServiceReference("some_implementation_config_key");

  public void RegisterProduct(productName, price)
  {
    iProductDomainService.Validate(productName);
  }
}

Regarding Enforcing Validation

We can potentially create a product without validating it through the domain service and directly save it. Is this a general practice, and should this be enforced or cross-checked in code reviews to ensure that validation isn't skipped?

The code paths for performing important domain-level actions should reduce down to single places in the code - e.g. for "Products" a single ProductDomainService with ideally one Save() method.  You'd place all the checks in there so that there was no way Save() will save data that fails any checks.
If you wanted to, you could create a method that only performed the checks, and make that public for pre-save validation, and also use it to do the actual validation inside of Save().
class ProductDomainService
{
  private IProductRepository iProductRepository = AmazingAbstractionService.GetServiceReference("respository.product");    


  public ValidationResults Validate(product)
  {
    // Do validation.
    // ValidationResults is a class you define 
    // which provides back any information you need to show that 
    // validation was successful, or failed and the reason(s) why it failed.

    return ValidationResults;
  }

  public ValidationResults Save(product)
  {
    ValidationResults validation = Validate(product);
    if(validation.Result == ProductConsts.ValidationPassed)
    {
      // Save/persist code, passing of to a repository implementation
      // which would be created using pattern described 
      // in the first code example above.
      iProductRepository.Persist(product);
    }
    else
    {
      // Contains the validation failure details.
      return validation;
    }
  }
}

Update

If persistence then what is purpose of writing validation types in the repository layer?

Typically you would validate an entity in the Domain Layer before passing it off to a Repository for persistence.  The Repository would not perform the validation - it would assume that the entity had been validated by the Domain Service.
I have updated the second code snippet to be more clear in that regard.

Saving where? Is is entity creation save or persistence ?
If persistence then  what is purpose of writing validation types in the repository layer?
I need to know do application layer handler the Validaiton (some of which are part of domain service ) and creation of the domain entity sepratly, if so then we can't enforce the valid domain entity creation, should we pass this domain service while creation or injecting the service in the domain class is better?
